# How To Fix: Data Recovery from Broken Screen without USB Debugging

Tags: cyanogenmod, data-recovery, broken-screen, oneplus-two

I have the OnePlus Two phone whose screen was broken a while ago and i want to back up some of my pictures and videos which were stacked in its internal memory. Please note the below points for better understanding:

1. Screen can show content but the touch is not responsive.
2. I don't have an OTG Type C connector.
3. USB Debugging was not active before phone was damaged.
4. Need some software which can help me project my phone screen on laptop/pc so that i can draw patterns or do stuff like transferring of data to Google Drive etc. in short i can access phone over PC.

Please advise me suitably over the above as I need to get out of this quick.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! First hint would be to check with our [broken-screen tag-wiki](/tags/broken-screen/info) and [other questions using that tag](/tags/broken-screen) (to further narrow it down, [here are the ones having at least 1 answer](/search?q=[broken-screen]+answers%3A1)), as this question is asked quite frequently. Then please [edit] your question to indicate you've checked that, including what you've tried and why the approaches you found didn't work for you. We don't want to duplicate our answers here :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you did not activate `adb` it may be active when the recovery is booted. (At least for recent versions of TWRP it is.)

Depending on what you want to do this may be enough. If it is not you could try enabling the OS's `adb` from recovery `adb` (see [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2335799) for an example of the relevant configuration files). After this is done [adbcontrol](http://marian.schedenig.name/2014/07/03/remote-control-your-android-phone-through-adb/) is can be used to remote control your phone using a computer and `adb`. If you use an unlock pattern that includes a polygon of swipes this will not help (a pin would be fine).

In this case you would have to reset the unlock code, but I messed up something on my phone which may have happened while doing this, so I am not comfortable giving you advice on how to do it. In any case make backups (e.g. via `adb pull`) even of you configuration files before doing any modifications.